# how to fix this error unknown option "--icmp-type"?

Tags: networking, error-handling

I want to block ICMP ping request and I have followed syntax from tutorials, but get the same result:

[image: error image]

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables) : unknown option "--icmp-type"
Try 'iptables -h' or 'iptables --help for more information.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on WSL by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the manual for `iptables`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/iptables.8.html) there is no `--icmp-type` option. That said, if you would like to block *all* ICMP requests, you can do this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Edit the `sysctl.conf` file with elevated permissions:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/sysctl.conf
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your preferred editor.</sup>
2. Add the following line to the end of the file:

   ```
   net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
   ```
3. Save the changes and exit the editor.
4. Apply the configuration change:

   ```
   sysctl -p
   ```

Now the system will ignore all ICMP requests. This change will persist across reboots, too.

Comment: The `--icmp-type` option is documented in the `iptables-extensions` man page I think ...